# CSS Div That Wraps Under With Shadow

Tags: html, css

I know this has probably been covered a few times on the web, but I don't think I know how to properly describe the effect i'm looking for as I can't seem to find any results. Its quite a popular trend these days where the div seems to wrap under the edges of its parent:

[image]

Similar to the header element on the menus in the image. Doesn't have to be rounded as in the picture, but a similar effect would be nice, and all in pure CSS if possible.

I'm at a complete loss of where to start here, and any insight would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Not a real relevant article, but thanks for the read.

Comment: Yes it is relevant, you are not providing any useful code for us to help you.

Comment: I apologize. I have no idea where to start here. Should I be using a border, a separate divs, backgrounds. I would provide some code, but I don't have any. Note I didn't necessarily ask for a complete snippet, just a starting point will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Guess this will help you!**

A pure implementation of [**CSS Ribbons**](https://catalin.red/css-ribbons/). [Demo here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160520052208/http://red-team-design.com:80/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/css-ribbons-demo.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [red-team-design.com](http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/css-ribbons.png))</sub>

Another implementation of the same, [**Pure CSS Ribbon Builder**](https://dribbble.com/shots/439245-Pure-CSS-Ribbon-Builder). [Builder here](https://web.archive.org/web/20190110053641/http://livetools.uiparade.com:80/ribbon-builder.html).

[image]

Or you can try this **Corner Ribbon**

You need to have this **HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="ribbon-wrapper-green"><div class="ribbon-green">NEWS</div></div>
</div>
```

And the **CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 280px;
  height: 370px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 90;
}

.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font: bold 15px Sans-Serif;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 7px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ribbon-green:before, .ribbon-green:after {
  content: "";
  border-top:   3px solid #6e8900;   
  border-left:  3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  position:absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green:before {
  left: 0;
}
.ribbon-green:after {
  right: 0;
}
```